# How to create package whatever is updated after the build in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

I have a Jenkins job that gets the code from version control and builds (like what a normal pipeline do), I was doing is that after building the project, I download the build and use FTP to transfer that build to the client's server then I unzip it and then copy the whole build because I copy whole build my application's down time is very high. (I have to use FTP because as a service provider we have some limitations and can't change this policy)

What I wanted to do is that Jenkins know what is changed when it is building so Jenkins will create a package with all the changes and with the correct path where the file should go, and I can download that package and copy that package and just run the package so whatever was changed only that should get updated.

Is that possible? Is there any plugin that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the build tool/language you are using to build you application. I dont think there is a generic jenkins plugin.

Other idea would be to upload your package to a local Nexus server. Download after the next build and the compare the files from old and new build. With this information you can create a patch package for your clienst server.

Comment: We have developed the solution in the .net so we are building in windows and also deploying in the windows based server only.

Comment: you should use powershell to find the updated files. compare-object commandlet is your friend.